# Can I receive items on Steam for games I don't own?

Tags: steam

I got a new account and want to receive items from my friend but I don't have any games. Is it possible to receive and sell items from, for example, CS:GO if I don't have CS:GO?

Answer (score 7):

## Yes! *

You can trade and sell items for games you do not own.

* <sub>Provided your account is in good standing and [not restricted from the Steam Marketplace](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1047-edfm-2932)</sub>

Comment: The Market is unavailable, because i don't have valid steam purchase. Does steam allow users to exchange items between each other if market is unavailable?

Comment: No, Steam doesn't allow users that have no games to add other users as friends due to them being restricted accounts.

Comment: There is something called Steam trade URL, you don't have to add user to exchange items. Is it possible to use it with unavailable market?

Comment: The Steam trade URLs go through the marketplace and would be subject to the same restrictions...

Answer (score 0):

Just put 5 bucks on the account and restrictions will be lifted. You will now be able to use the marketplace.